# Angular JS - instantly updating view

Tags: angularjs

I would like to instantly update {{card.likeCount}} (on the HTML page) when user click on like anchor tag.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>

            <li>
                <i class="fa fa-eye">
                </i>
                {{card.likeCount}}
            </li>
            <li>
                <a  href="#" ng-click="likingCard(card.id)" name>
                    Like
                    </i>
                </a>
            </li>
```

This is how I currently do it, I add this code to cardCtrl, I'm not sure if I'm using the right approach:

```
    $scope.likingCard = function(id) {
    $http.post('/card/like/', {
        id: id
    }).then(function onSuccess(result, status, headers, config) {

        setTimeout(function() {
            $scope.likeCount = parseInt(result.data.likeCount);
            console.log($scope.likeCount);
            $scope.$digest();
        }, 1000);

    }).catch(function onError(err) {
        console.log('Error:', err);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why, when you say "instantly update", you have inserted a deliberate 1 second delay after receiving the response before you update the model.

If you don't want the delay, just update the model:

```
$scope.likingCard = function(id) {
    $http.post('/card/like/', {
        id: id
    }).then(function (result) {
            $scope.likeCount = parseInt(result.data.likeCount);
            console.log($scope.likeCount);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Error:', err);
    })
}
```

If you do want the delay then don't use `setTimeout`, use `$timeout` instead and you won't need the explicit call to `$digest`.

```
$scope.likingCard = function(id) {
$http.post('/card/like/', {
    id: id
}).then(function (result) {

    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.likeCount = parseInt(result.data.likeCount);
        console.log($scope.likeCount);
    }, 1000);

}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log('Error:', err);
})
```

}

Answer (score 0):

make use of ng-cloak directive

```
<body ng-cloak>
<!-- all your angular stuff here -->
</body>
```

you can also use ng-cloak directly on `<html>` tag

for more details check documentation here

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak